# Error on the mean of a random sample (in the case of imbalanced data/extreme skew/rare events/low rates)

Tags: sampling, mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, rare-events

**Background**

The standard error on the mean of a random sample $X$ of size $n$ is given by:

$$ s = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} $$

where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the population. But is it appropriate to use the standard deviation of $X$ when the data is so imbalanced/skewed?

**Example: being struck by lightning**

Being struck by lightning is a rare event. The longer a person lives, the more times they will have likely been hit, but still the vast majority will have been struck $0$ times per year on average. Note that I am looking at this from the perspective of *rates*, and not *proportions* (e.g., a person could be struck twice in their lifetime which would change the overall population rate, but the population proportion would remain unchanged).

Owing to the rarity of the event, the vast majority of subjects will have experienced a strike rate of $0$ strikes year$^{-1}$. For example:

```
i     x        y     r
      strikes  age   rate
--------------------------
1     0        30    0.00
2     0        45    0.00
3     1        50    0.02
4     0        70    0.00
--------------------------
1bn   500      5tn   0.0000001
```

To account for age, the mean rate of being struck by lightning is:

$$ r = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^N x_i}{\sum_{i=0}^N y_i}$$

where $x_i$ is the times that subject $i$ has been struck by lightning, and $y_i$ is the subject's age. When aggregated over the whole population, a given person will be struck with a rate $r$ strikes year$^{-1}$. In the example, a population of $N=1\times 10^9$ subjects yield $r=1.0\times10^{-7}$ strikes year$^{-1}$.

**Question**

1. If a random sample of $n$ is taken from this population, and the aggregated rate, $r$, is measured, then what will the standard error on the mean (rate) be?
2. Can the standard deviation be calculated like this?

$$\frac{ \sum_{i=0}^n y_i (\frac{x_i}{y_i}-\bar{r})^2}{\sum_{i=0}^n y_i}$$

and is it even appropriate to calculate the standard deviation in this way with such extremely low rates / rare events / high prevalence of $r_i=0$?

3. If not, can you suggest what should be used when finding the error on the mean of extremely inbalanced data?